# Can I export the list of installed packages in a machine-readable format?

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package, chocolatey

The only way I have seen to get a list of installed chocolatey packages is with "choco version all" which outputs something like this:

```
You have SourceTree v1.9.1.1 installed. Version 1.9.6.1 is available based on your source(s).

You have sysinternals v2016.07.04 installed. Version 2016.08.29 is available based on your source(s).

Chocolatey can upgrade 5/9 packages. 0 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Can upgrade:
 - 7zip.install v16.02.0.20160811
 - chocolatey v0.10.0
 - sourcetree v1.9.6.1
 - 7zip v16.02.0.20160811
 - sysinternals v2016.08.29
```

For interactive console output thats fine, but for parsing to create a report it stinks. Is there some way I can get this info in xml or json or some standardized format instead of having to parse the above myself?

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts: 

1. You are complaining about a command that was deprecated almost two years ago - that command is now `choco outdated`. 

2. The command for seeing locally installed stuff shouldn't be running something that is checking what is upgradeable - `choco list -lo -r` is what you are looking for for what is installed. It runs in about 1 second.

Comment: "deprecated almost two years ago"... "`choco outdated`"... hmmm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost all chocolatey commands make use of the `-r, --limitoutput, --limit-output` switch, which means:

> Limit the output to essential information

See this [page](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-reference) for more information about what switches are available.

By doing `choco version all -r` you will get a much more parseable output.  For example:

```
7zip|9.22.01.20130618|16.02.0.20160811|false
7zip.commandline|16.02|16.02.0.20160811|false
7zip.install|9.22.01.20130618|16.02.0.20160811|false
Atom|0.174.1|1.0.7|false
autohotkey.portable|1.1.22.01|1.1.24.01|false
BingDesktop|1.3.463.0|1.3.463.0|false
Boxstarter|2.4.209|2.8.29|false
```

However, you are asking about a command to export the list of "installed" packages.

#### choco list -lo -r

That command is documented as `choco list --local-only`. It **runs in about one second** and the output looks like this when `choco list -lo -r`:

```
7zip|9.22.01.20130618
7zip.commandline|16.02
7zip.install|9.22.01.20130618
Atom|0.174.1
autohotkey.portable|1.1.22.01
BingDesktop|1.3.463.0
Boxstarter|2.4.209
Boxstarter.Common|2.4.209
cake.portable|0.15.2
calibre|2.48.0
ccleaner|5.19.5633
chocolatey|0.10.0
chocolatey.extension|1.4.1
ChocolateyGUI|0.14.0-unstable0002
ChocolateyPackageUpdater|0.6.11.0
```